# better performance for this sql algorithm?

Tags: sql, algorithm, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm looking for alternative SQL code

My table has 4 columns : `Id, Zip code, timestamp and user value.`

Row Example :`2299898;"40";"2011-03-28 00:45:00+02";1.9`

I want to get the result set for one day for each zip code where the time equals or is before a timestamp. And obviously the user data for each line.

My query so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FIRST_VALUE(timestamp) OVER (
        PARTITION BY zipcode, DATE(timestamp)
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    ) AS timestamp,
    zipcode,
    FIRST_VALUE(userdata) OVER (
        PARTITION BY zipcode, DATE(timestamp)
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    ) AS userdata
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Performance questions are almost always product specific.

Comment: Hi jarlh, It's postgres 9.1,

Comment: What's the performance issue you're having? Execution times taking longer than expected? Have you used `EXPLAIN` to generate an execution plan yet?

Comment: i tried to be faster, my attempt include a new column with DATE(timestamp) but no significative time reduction

Comment: Hello Jonathan. Indeed, the trouble is the execution time. EXPLAIN shows that OVER PARTITION BY is really expensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the window functions:

```
select distinct on (zipcode, timestamp::date)
    timestamp,
    zipcode,
    userdata
from t
order by zipcode, timestamp::date desc, timestamp desc
```

Check [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

Comment: it seems to be perfect. I should test on the real database (tomorrow)  before closing the thread but first tests on my local one show that your query is ten times more efficient.
Thanks, really appreciate your answer.